# Which is more natural English: "I don't know what the cause is" or "I don't know what is the cause"?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, word-usage, american-english, british-english

1. I don't know what the cause is.
2. I don't know what is the cause.

and do you have any difference between these sentences.
if you have, could you explain it.
e.g. 1) is for writing, 2) is for speaking

Answer (score -1):

> I don't know what the cause is.

This is the correct one because you are not asking a question. You are just saying that you don't know what the cause is.

> I don't know what is the cause.

This one is not correct. The inversion in the sentence is making it a question and in the meantime there is "I don't know" which doesn't have inversion and is not making it a question.

Comment: No, the inversion is not making it a question. Would it be a question to say "I don't know what is the cause of your acne?"

Comment: While I agree the first is more *natural* English, I agree with Robusto that the second is not a question, at least not as punctuated.  *"I don't know.  What is the cause?"* would be a question.

Comment: They mean the same thing. Neither strikes me an unnatural English. I have heard and used both.